# Can anyone name and interpret the upside down cursive e with flair in attached image?

Tags: meaning

On 20 Mar 1718/19 a scribe wrote in the Lancashire, Church of England, Bishops' Transcripts  "20 Thomas Son to Þe late Rever M.ɚ Ogden".  This is a burial record.  As best I can interpret it, it reads "20 Thomas Son to the late Reverend M. Ogden"  However, I do not know what the ɚ is.  It appears in superscript between the M. and Ogden.  It looks like an upside down cursive e with a tail or flair. An image is attached.  Can anyone tell me what it is an how it should be interpreted?[image]

Comment: Do you have a larger picture so that we can see the breadth of script elsewhere in the page?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to say "Reverend M<sup>r</sup> Ogden". The abbreviation "Mr" was sometimes written with a superscript, similar to how people still write *1<sup>st</sup>*. You can see another example of this in this picture: [The Reverend M<sup>r</sup> James Hervey](https://www.ngv.vic.gov.au/explore/collection/work/38000/) (1751).

Comment: Agreed. It's a superscript lowercase 'r'. I have seen lots of these.

Comment: Yes, in England the term "Reverend" was, and officially still is so far as I know, considered to be a description rather than a title; so as an Anglican priest he would have been referred to as "the Reverend Mr Ogden" and, when addressed directly  would have been called "Mr Ogden" rather than "Reverend Ogden". "Reverend Ogden" would be what most people say now but it is an import from American practice.